# Copying and Pasting the Results of a Loop calculation using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA calculation that is looping to recalculate cells 500 (or whatever the iteration is) times. For each recalculation there is an output which I want a record of after the loop is complete. I have tried a few different ways but I can't seem to get it right. Here is an example of what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
   Iteration = Range("C4")

   For i = 1 To Iteration
     Range("C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20").Calculate
     Range("C20").Copy
     Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select.PasteSpecial  xlPasteValues
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't appear to be changing anything as you loop through *x* number of times (*x* being the number in C4). Shouldn't you be changing a value somewhere before recalculating and storing the result(s)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you explain what result you get, and why it is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
   Dim val as Variant
   Iteration = Range("C4")

   For i = 1 To Iteration
       Range("C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20").Calculate
       val = Range("C20").Value

       Debug.print "i: " & i & " val: " & val
       Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = val
   Next i
End Sub
```

If the correct values do not show up in the immediate window, the problem lies elsewhere. Obviously, delete the `debug.print` statement, if the code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem is that you are selecting in the same line as pasting special. Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
Iteration = Range("C4")


For i = 1 To Iteration
  Range("C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20").Calculate
Range("C20").Copy
Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The `.PasteSpecial` is offset 1 row down for each new paste.

Comment: Is that incorrect? I assumed @BPCG wanted the value from C20 to be put into the next available cell in column J.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same wavelength. Yes, each new paste goes into a new row in column J. That is why I was questioning the first sentence in your post.

Comment: I have to agree, I feel as though I am missing something! The OPs code was offsetting down 1 row, correct? I know that I also qualified the column offset as 0 (unnecessary, but I like it), but the only real change was to take the select out of the line `Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: I see clearly now! Yes... good catch! I see where you were going now. The OP has not asked a good question and has not followed up with clarification asked of him/her.

Comment: Apologies for not adding clarification - I have been offline but thank you for your input. What I am trying to do is copy the result of each loop and then paste that in to another column so I have a list of the iterations.

Comment: @BPCG The code I posted should work then. It will paste each iteration under the last in column J. Please mark my answer as accepted if it works for you. Post back if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Iteration As Integer, i As Integer
    Iteration = Range("C4")

Dim RLog As Range              ' prepare a range for the log
    Set RLog = [C22]           ' or wherever you want to start the log range

    For i = 1 To Iteration
        Range("C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20").Calculate

        RLog(i,1) = [C20]      ' write the current result to the range (short notation [C20] is aequivalent to Range("R20")
    Next i
End Sub
```